# Remove duplicates from a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm writing my first python program to manage users in Atlassian On Demand using their RESTful API.  I call the users/search?username= API to retrieve lists of users, which returns JSON.    The results is a list of complex dictionary types that look something like this:

```
[
        {
            "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=fred",
            "name": "fred",
            "avatarUrls": {
                "24x24": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=fred",
                "16x16": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=fred",
                "32x32": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=fred",
                "48x48": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&ownerId=fred"
            },
            "displayName": "Fred F. User",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=andrew",
            "name": "andrew",
            "avatarUrls": {
                "24x24": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=andrew",
                "16x16": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=andrew",
                "32x32": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=andrew",
                "48x48": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&ownerId=andrew"
            },
            "displayName": "Andrew Anderson",
            "active": false
        }
    ]
```

I'm calling this multiple times and thus getting duplicate people in my results.  I have been searching and reading but cannot figure out how to deduplicate this list.  I figured out how to sort this list using a lambda function.  I realize I could sort the list, then iterate and delete duplicates.  I'm thinking there must be a more elegant solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usernames are unique, right?

Does it have to be a `list`? Seems like an easy solution would be to make it a `dict` of `dict`s instead. Use the usernames as keys, and only the most recent version will be present.

If the values have to be ordered, there is an `OrderedDict` type you could look into: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: the RESTful interface has to be called several times to get all the users, thus the usernames are not unique in the combined list.  For now, I sorted the list using a custom sort function, then iterated in reverse through the list removing the duplicates.  Seems like there would be an easier solution though.

Comment: I didn't mean the usernames would be unique within the list; I meant that I expect that each username corresponds to exactly one user (so you wouldn't have to worry about conflicting entries in a `dict`). Anthony Kong posted what I was getting at; that link I posted is only useful if the order of the usernames matters, but I assume it probably doesn't.

Comment: Ah - gotcha.  Yes - you were right.  Regarding sort order, I converted  the dictionary back to a list, then used the sort() method with a lambda function...fast, quick, easy, and much more elegant than my manual duplicate detection.   Thanks much for pointing me to the right path!!

Answer (score 0):

Let say it is what you got,

```
JSON = [
        {

            "name": "fred",
...
},
        {

            "name": "peter",
...
},
        {

            "name": "fred",
...
},
```

Convert this list of dict to a dict of dict will remove the duplicate, like so:

```
r = dict([(user['name'], user) for user in JSON])
```

In `r` you will only find one record of fred and peter each.

Comment: The comprehension would be a lot less noisy as a dict comprehension: `{user['name']: user for user in JSON}`

Comment: Nice!  Works!  Thank you!

Comment: Just to close the loop on this...here is my final code  `result = dict([(user.name, user) for user in result])  
    result = [value for key, value in result.iteritems()]  
    result.sort(key=lambda d: d.name)`